# How to print or return the final value of the iteration from loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the last value from the iteration. Code is as follows:

```
x = int(input("enter "))
y = []
while x > 0:
    y += [x]
    x = x-1

    def multiply(mlist):
        result1 = 1
        for z in mlist:
            result1 = result1 * z
        return result1

    print(y)
    print(multiply(y))
```

Example: input integer 3 then output is as follows:

```
[3]
3
[3, 2]
6
[3, 2, 1]
6
```

How do I print only:

```
[3, 2, 1]
6
```

Comment: Pls fix the indentation to what you actually have in your code (what you posted is not correct Python syntax). Assuming the while loop is only two lines, your code generates your desired output.

Comment: Don't find any issue here if your indentation is correct. After fixing the indentation the result I got is matching to your expected output

Comment: How to print the final iterated value only?

Comment: please mention your expected output? @B.LeeN

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**

```
def multiply(mlist):
    result1 = 1
    for z in mlist:
        result1 = result1 * z
    return result1


x = int(input("enter "))
y = []

while x > 0:
    y += [x]
    x = x-1

print(y)
print(multiply(y))
```

**Output:**

```
enter 3
[3, 2, 1]
6
```

Comment: I asked how to print final iteration value from while loop.

Comment: And the program does exactly that. @Sabil fixed the indentation error and moved the function definition to a more appropriate place (really, a function definition in the middle of the loop. what kind of monster writes such a thing?).